# how to retrieve char array from class in jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, char, jnienv

I am passing the object of class from java to `JNI`. I have retrieved the class using `GetObjectClass`.

```
Jclass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,Jobj);
```

I can get the value of integer in the class by using

```
fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,Jclass, "JValue", "I");
Value = (*env)->GetIntField(env, Jobj, fid);
```

and I can get the `String` value using `GetObjectField` and `GetStringUTFChars`.

How can I get a `Char Array` present in the `Java` class from `JNI`?

Comment: `GetFieldID` using `"[C"` as the descriptor; [`GetCharArrayElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17382) to get `jchar *`

Comment: Thanks.How to get the char array using fieldid?

Comment: `GetObjectField`, then, as I stated, `GetCharArrayElements` to get `jchar *`

Comment: How to get the jchar* using **fieldid**?

Comment: ... do you understand English? PS I highly suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) before posting questions like this.

Comment: @veer how will you set a char variable inside a class from jni?? anyidea??

Comment: @jxgn [`SetCharField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16613) :-)

Comment: @veer thanks :) one more help, i have a jchararray. I need to set the data from this jchararray to a char[] in java which is inside a class........